# Is this series convergent or divergent? How to test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Considering the series: 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1+n^{\frac{1}{n^2+1}})$.

How can I **use limiting comparison test** to show that it converges or diverges? And how about using another test method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=-1+n^{\frac 1 {n^{2}+1}}=-1+e^{\frac 1 {n^{2}+1} \log n}$. Let $b_n=\frac 1 {n^{2}+1} \log n$,. Then $\frac {a_n} {b_n} \to 1$ because $\frac {e^{x}-1}x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. I leave it to you to show that $ \sum b_n$ is convergent. This shows that $\sum a_n$ is also convergent.